# beforeUpdate afterUpdate

Tags: grails, event-triggers

do we have beforeUpdateOf* (where * is some field?)

and another question :

> def beforeUpdate= { log.info("in beforeUpdate " +this.status) }
>
> def afterUpdate = { log.info("in afterUpdate " +this.status) }

This both gives same status.
Although actually status of object(this) is updated from x to y

Answer (score 3):

There's no event for when a property is changed, but you could add in an explicit setter that does something:

```
class MyDomainClass {
   String status

   void setStatus(String status) {
      this.status = status
      // do something based on changed value
   }
}
```

You're seeing the same value in `beforeUpdate` and `afterUpdate` because those callbacks are for when Hibernate saves the changed values to the database. It would be unusual for the value to change between the time that Hibernate starts and finishes the update.

If you're looking for the original value from the database, it's available using http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getPersistentValue.html

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Be careful although with "this.status = status" provoking infinite recursion. I solved that calling super.setStatus(newStatus) in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at grails audit plugins: [Audit Logging](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) and [Audit Trail](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging)